# Windows Authentication feature for SQL Server through PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a basic script to connect to a SQL Server instance using SMO in PowerShell and obtain the required data.

Now, it uses Windows authentication that SQL Server allows the account running the PowerShell script. But I want a way such that if suppose the current account doesn't have access to the server, then it can enter another Windows authentication credential. i.e another username and password with higher access to connect to the server.

Is there any PowerShell script or command to enter another credentials?

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Credential` is the preferred way if the cmdlets you're running support the `-Credential` option.  If you're using SMO objects directly, then it'll depend on exactly what the classes and methods you're using require.